# MITMProxy 7.0.4 + Android emulator AVD 30

Tags: android, emulation, mitmproxy

1. Installed MITMProxy on Win 10 (10.0.19043).
2. Installed root certificate with `cd C:\Users\xxx\.mitmproxy;certutil.exe -addstore root mitmproxy-ca-cert.cer`.
3. Installed root certificate in AVD 30 according to https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/howto-install-system-trusted-ca-android/
4. Tried to access "Youtube" app and got "You're offline..."
5. If I open a `https` connection with chrome, I get "Your connection is not private".
6. Output of `adb shell ls –al /system/etc/security/cacerts/c8750f0d.0` is `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1172 2021-10-19 07:51 /system/etc/security/cacerts/c8750f0d.0`, so I assume root certificate is properly installed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: More specific: How can I get MITMProxy to catch the HTTPS traffic from Android emulator?

Comment: Most Google apps use certificate pinning so the installed root CA cert doesn't work. To get traffic of such apps I would recommend to use a Magisk rooted device and install "Riru" + "Riru edXposed" + Xposed module TrustMeAlready. Alternatively you can try Frida + Objection.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to prevent certificate pinning :-). With [Frida](https://github.com/frida/frida) and [Objection](https://github.com/sensepost/objection) you can can disable certificate pinning an use MITMProxy to catch all traffic!

Comment: Maybe it would be better for future readers if you as well provided steps how to do it.

Comment: Sure: Install Frida and Objection (after installing MITM root certificate) and then start Objections. That's it!